# Find the fake bar in 2 weighing

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, strategy, optimization, weighing

You are given 8 equal sized bars of silver labeled a to h. You know for a fact one of them is fake, and the only measurable difference is weight. However you do not know if the fake bar is heavier or lighter. You are also given a balance scale which can be used to compare weight between two bars or sets of bars. However, you are restricted to using the scale only twice. Find the fake one in 2 weighing.
Given: Bars e,f,g,h are collectively lighter than bars a,b,c,d.

Comment: Is the balance scale can be used to compare weight between **two bars** or **two sets of bars**?

Comment: You can compare between two or sets of bars.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake it's bars.

Comment: That just explains the algorithm for number of steps required for N number of balls. What I ask is not the number of steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### first weighing

> we know either a,b,c or d is heavier, or e,f,g or h is lighter 
>  on one side, a, b, and e, on the other, c, d and f

### second weighing

if the first weighing is equal

> this means either g or h is the lighter. we just have to put them on each side to see wich one is the lighter

if the left part is heavier

> this means either a or b is heavier, or f is lighter. we just have to weight a and b, if a is heavier, the fake bar is a. if b is heavier, it's the fake bar. if the weigh is equal, f is the fake one.

if the right part is heavier

> this means either c or d is heavier, or e is lighter. we just have to weight c and d, if c is heavier, the fake bar is c. if d is heavier, it's the fake bar. if the weigh is equal, e is the fake one.

Comment: d can't be lighter than f, as a,b,c,d are collectively heavier than e,f,g,h and since 7 of them weigh exactly the same, d can't be the lighter fake one.

Comment: Yeah the way you worded the question I don't think is very appropriate...Even given which group of bars is lighter it would be impossible to determine which of the bars is the lightest without actually having the bars to weigh. This answer IS the solution.